# how to update masterfile once file is opened by each users at same time

Tags: excel, vba

Need a Quick help here to achieve the following,

There are multiple users who access one of the template file that i have given to them. It is individual file, not shared file.
Once each user opens the file, time stamp will be published in A1 cell and User name in B1 cell.

The need here is, I have Master file with list of user names from A1,A2 and goes on.

once each user opens the individual file the master file should get updated against respective user id as "Y" in Master file.

Challenge here is , every user would be opening the file at same time. So this should not create any issue such as Master file is read only or should not over ride each others data as such.

Please help.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me - you want the individual files to send an update to a master file but it won't overwrite the stuff on the masterfile.. it'll just add a new row or what? Sounds to me like maybe you need a database not a spreadsheet for the master

Comment: Easy work around: Instead of trying to write back "Y" to a cell in the masterfile each time a template is opened, just *create individual text files* with the (*encryted*) username as file name and collect this information independently and directly from the masterfile via directory search (e.g. using a `Dir` loop).